# discord.py: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I am trying to write a bot that adds a custom emoji from the attachments of a message and I'm getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 218, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\python projects\votingbot.py", line 84, in on_message
    await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=emoji_name, image=img)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1202, in create_custom_emoji
    img = utils._bytes_to_base64_data(image)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 264, in _bytes_to_base64_data
    mime = _get_mime_type_for_image(data)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 251, in _get_mime_type_for_image
    if data.startswith(b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A'):
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
# obviously the setup stuff like def on_message is cut out for brevity

url = message.attachments[0].url
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
emoji_name = message.content.replace("!addemojipoll ","")
await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=emoji_name, image=img)
```

Is it because `img` is not a byte-like object, as required by `create_custom_emoji`?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that at some point, `discord.py` got an `JpegImageFile` object while expecting an object which supports `.startswith(b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A')`. This is, as you guessed, a bytes-like object.

So you should use a `bytes` object instead of a PIL object; and this even makes your code simpler, because you had a bytes object from the beginning:

```
response = requests.get(url)
img = response.content
await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=emoji_name, image=img)
```